# array code error

Tags: php, sql

I have an array but something goes wrong with it, here is my code :

```
 $date = array (1 => "$row['turning']", 2 => "$row['smiling']");
```

and this code is displaying this error

> unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE
>   or T_NUM_STRING

some light please .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your variable is an array then you need to enclose it in curly brackets:

```
$date = array (1 => "{$row['turning']}", 2 => "{$row['smiling']}");
```

Although you should just do:

```
$date = array (1 => $row['turning'], 2 => $row['smiling']);
```

Comment: thanks so much :) , its right :), it works like a charme now .

Comment: 1-   for ($j=1 ; $j <= 10 ; $j ++){
            2-       $date = array (1 => $row['turning'], 2 => $row['smiling']);
            3-   $year."$j"= substr($date[$j], 6, 4) ; }


say that i have date like that 2012-03-25
after this code i get this error 
unexpected '=' in line 3
something wrong there ?

Comment: You can't concatenate two variables and then try to assign a value to it.

Comment: i mean i wanted get  date1 and date2 from each one (turning and smiling columns ), is there someway better ?